# Can I make R# intellisense select the first list item?

Tags: resharper, intellisense, resharper-5.x

I'm using ReSharper 5.1 in VS2010, and I've been annoyed by the intellisense behavior for quite a while.  It seems this is different since R# 4.5/VS2008, but I don't have that combo handy to verify.

Let's say I'm typing some code:

```
...
public Guid teamId { get; set; }
...
```

And later on I decide I want to make `teamId` a read-only property, so I go back to put `private` in front of `set`.  As I start typing, I end up with this:

[image: picture of R# Intellisense menu]

At this point, I have to either switch to the mouse or the arrow keys, or just finish typing `private`, which really defeats the purpose of this feature.

Is there a way to tell ReSharper to select an entry as soon as the Intellisense popup appears?

Comment: Nope - I end up with `pr[Tab character] set`

Comment: I have noticed this too in the latest version... no solution yet though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Space to have "pr" expanded to "private"
If you press Ctrl+Space "before starting to type "pr", you'll get a completion list with all applicable options and a properly working focus over one of them.

Comment: +1 - Certainly a good workaround, although I'm going to leave it open a while to see if somebody knows of a setting to fix the problem in question

Comment: After 15 minutes of using this feature, I actually like it a lot better *because* I can use it with my right hand on the arrow keys.  It makes turning a bunch of automatically implemented properties into readonly properties much simpler.

Comment: Not selecting an item in the completion list that is displayed automatically (as opposed to explicitly by pressing Ctrl+Space) definitely feels like a bug. Here's a bug report that you can vote for: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-195419

Comment: Thank you for opening that - I'll vote it up when I can log in (they seem to be having a problem with OpenID at the moment).